# update sonarqube to 7.0 not possible because of sonar-10131 fix

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I was trying to update to sonarqube 7.0 (from 6.7.2)
The fix for ticket [SONAR-10131](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-10131) "purge of db Table Project measures is incomplete", prevents us from updating. 
 The running time for each statement takes longer then 14 hours, and we have 492 projects. The number of rows for table project_measures is  5,4 million.
Database is an oracle 12c,  PGA 2GB RAM, statistics are refreshed. The statement is not appropriate for full tables on oracle instances. It will be always an full table scan for the "exist clause" 
We already deleted all entries with the script provided in the ticket. (We materialized the inner select). So this delete statement is not needed anymore. Can we skip this part of the database migration step? Is there another way to migrate to sonarqube 7.0.  Below is the statement which is executed for each project.

```
delete from project_measures pm where exists (
    select 1 from project_measures pm2   
    inner join projects c on c.uuid = pm2.component_uuid   
    where pm2.analysis_uuid = :1    and 
    (c.qualifier in ('UTS', 'FIL') 
    or pm.person_id is not null)   and pm.id = pm2.id
)
```